# Cloud syncing to central database from local servers laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, cloud

For my project, there are webapps installed on local servers. Whenever there is internet connection available, a press of a sync button on local server app should sync the database and the user uploaded files with central server. The central server should know from where the data is coming. I am building the local server apps using laravel 4.2. Is there a simple way I can achieve this?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using an extra column `synced` in all the tables on both local and cloud server and wrote code to send data through JSON APIs. Then, I updated the `synced` column with `timestamp` on both ends. And then on every sync button press, I compared `updated` and `synced` column and sent the data to the server accordingly.

I don't know if this is the perfect solution but worked for me.